# URL Request timeout error for the webfrontend example running Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I followed the example below and got to the end without error

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/quickstart-helm

except that a timeout error occurs for the external IP address below,

http://20.62.159.20/

Any idea?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by the docker registry credential. The doc does not show you how to set it for the ACR. There are two ways to solve it. One is that you can attach the ACR to the AKS cluster with the CLI command:

```
az aks update -g mygroup -n myaks --attach-acr myacr
```

Another way is to use a secret for the ACR. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-kubernetes) are the steps to create the secret with the service principal, you can also use the admin user and password of the ACR. Then change the file `values.yaml` like this:

```
imagePullSecrets:
    - name: secretName
```

Comment: This command has been run. `az aks create -g MyResourceGroup -n MyAKS --location eastus  --attach-acr MyHelmACR --generate-ssh-keys` Does it mean it doesn't work like the first command you provided.

Comment: @Pingpong No, both of them work into the same result. It seems your image is in the ACR named HelloHelmACR, not MyHelmACR. Do you make the mistake?

Comment: Yes, I changed it to HelloHelmACR on the example showed on the screenshot.

Comment: @Pingpong So does it solve your problem? If it works for you please accept it.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but it seems good.